# Lombok - maven compilation failure "error: cannot access MappedSuperClass"

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I started using project lombok and noticed that command line compilation from maven fails on a clean compile. Code compiles under eclipse though.

I have lombok dependency in my POM as specified.

```
[INFO] Spring, Axon, Spring security, REST API, Websockets  SUCCESS [0.300s]
[INFO] springagain-contracts ............................. SUCCESS [1.881s]
[INFO] springagain-engine ................................ FAILURE [0.998s]
[INFO] springagain-web ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.344s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 09 12:49:03 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/181M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project springagain-engine: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: cannot access MappedSuperclass
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I have searched high and low and the only related issue is https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=352 however, it doesn't elaborate much on how it was fixed.

My code's here https://bitbucket.org/raghur/springagain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dependency. Adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

should solve that precise issue.
There is a bit more context here: https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=352

Comment: Fixed it. I'm still puzzled though - don't use JPA at all anywhere in the project. Guess it's transitive dependencies someplace :(